# ConcurrentBag performance

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

I've read in a lot of literature that ConcurrentBag is faster due to less synchronization overhead. Internally for each thread that adds items to it, it creates a separate data store, so it doesn't have to deal with synchronization. If I pull data out from it, it will pull it from the that particular thread's data store. If not present it will steal from other thread's queues. The part I don't understand is in most normal cases it wont be the same threads pulling out the data and stealing is inherently much slower than normal synchronization, then how can it be said that it is faster.

E.g if I have a producer consumer pattern where i don't care about ordering with some producer threads adding data to ConcurrentBag and some other thread dequeing it, my performance would be significantly impacted as it would never be the same thread pulling the data out as the producer threads and yet I see the same example as an application. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Faster than what? `ConcurrentBag` has best performance when the normal case is that of a single thread adding and removing items. If you want a pure producer/consumer, where one thread is adding and another is removing, then you probably want to use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the default [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the backing store.

Comment: Faster as compared to BlockingCollection or any synchronized queue

Comment: @Rahul `BlockingCollection` works on top of whatever `IProducerConsumerCollection` you pass it (which could be a `ConcurrentBag` as well), so that's a bad example :) In any case, the point is that the savings only work if the producer and consumer can run on the same thread. This does not include most producer/consumer scenarios, but it's very helpful if the cross-threading can be avoided most of the time.

Comment: @Luaan: My point is that "stealing" in `ConcurrentBag` is more expensive than dequeuing an item from `ConcurrentQueue`. So if you *know* that your producer and consumer are on different threads, then you're better off using `ConcurrentQueue`. And, yes, I know that `BlockingCollection` uses whatever `IProducerConsumerCollection` you give it. That's why I specifically said "the default `ConcurrentQueue`."

Comment: @JimMischel Yeah, I've been responding to Rahul's comment, not yours :)